# SqlException: An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ')'

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

This is the query I am trying to run against EF7

```
_context.Event.Where(e => e.Invitations.Any(i => i.User.Id == currentUserId));
```

Fairly simple query indeed and I can't see any non-boolean phrase passed as a condition.

`Event` here is in a one-to-many relationship with `Invitation`.

Comment: Could it be this one? https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/3317

Comment: This link shows how to see the SQL linq is generating which may help confirm the issue: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mpeder/archive/2014/06/16/how-to-see-the-actual-sql-query-generated-by-entity-framework.aspx

Comment: @WiktorZychla  could you post that as an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am posting an answer accepted by the OP: looks like there is a known bug in the sql generator, a bug the team is aware of:

https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/3317

Comment: Glad I found this. I guess until the Entity-Framework-Core 1.0 is released (with the fixes) we will have to use the workaround of `.Count(expr)>0` instead the more efficient `.Any(expr)`

Comment: @realavaloro I tried that, which resulted in some weird bug where it for some reason created the SQL `[t].[TablenameFieldname]`, where of course the latter doesn't work. I'll have to try something else.